# Build failed with XC8 compiler: error the PIC18 extended instruction set was enabled

Tags: pic, microchip

As per the Microchip's guidelines, I downloaded MPLAB X IDE 3.8v and also installed the XC8 compiler version 1.38. I wrote the following example code for blinking LEDs:

Configure registers like this:

```
#include<xc.h>

// CONFIG1L
#pragma config WDTEN = OFF      // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on SWDTEN bit))
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Reset on stack overflow/underflow enabled)
#pragma config XINST = ON       // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode enabled)

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Program memory is not code-protected)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config FOSC = ECPLL     // Oscillator Selection bits (EC Oscillator, PLL enabled, CLKO on RA6)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor enabled)
#pragma config IESO = ON        // Two-Speed Start-up (Internal/External Oscillator Switchover) Control bit (Two-Speed Start-up enabled)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscaler Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3L

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = DEFAULT // ECCP2 MUX bit (ECCP2/P2A is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config MSSPMSK = MSK7   // MSSP Address Masking Mode Select bit (7-Bit Address Masking mode enable)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.
```

And my code is:

```
#include<xc.h>

#include"config.h"

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

void main()

{

  TRISB=0X00;

  PORTB=0X00;

  while(1)

  { 

    PORTB=0XFF;

    __delay_ms(1000);

    PORTB=0X00;

    __delay_ms(1000);

  }

}
```

The issue is:

> config.h:13: error: (1504) the PIC18 extended instruction set was
>   enabled

but is not supported by this compiler

> (908) exit status = 1
>
> nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:100: recipe for target
>   'build/default/production/main.p1' failed
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory
>
> '/Users/saiteja/MPLABXProjects/TEST.X/example.X'
>
> nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:84: recipe for target '.build-conf'
>   failed
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory
>
> '/Users/saiteja/MPLABXProjects/TEST.X/example.X'
>
> nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
>
> make[2]: *** [build/default/production/main.p1] Error 1
>
> make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
>
> make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
>
> BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 468ms)

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty self-explanatory..

> config.h:13: error: (1504) the PIC18 extended instruction set was
>   enabled

It means that the MPLAB XC8 compiler (which is based on the HI-TECH C compiler) does not support PIC18's extended instruction set.

Change this line:

```
#pragma config XINST = ON
```

to this:

```
#pragma config XINST = OFF
```

And it should work fine.

---

Additional info:

- http://microchip.wikidot.com/faq:14
- MPLAB® XC8 C Compiler User’s Guide:

> The compiler support all instruction sets for PIC10/12/16 devices as
>   well as the standard (legacy) PIC18 instruction set. The extended
>   instruction mode available on some PIC18 devices is not currently
>   supported. Ensure you set the Configuration bits to use the PIC18
>   legacy instruction mode when appropriate.